# Date value chang when importing from CSV

Tags: php, date, format

I have data in a csv like that :

```
"id","timeZone","date"
"XE1DjjAru01tz8H7qhBluQ","America/Toronto","2014-02-12 16:29"
```

I have a class that look like this :

```
class MyClass {

    public $ID;
    public $Date;
}
```

For a reason that I don't understand, the date is not the same when I set the Date attribute of the myClass object. During the loop, the value of the variable $value = 2014-02-12 16:29 but when I set the Date attribute of the class myClass, it's equal to : 2014-02-12 16:02. Someone have an explanation about this please ?

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

    $num = count($data);

    if ($row === 1) {

        $fields = $data;
        $row++;
    } else {

        $row++;

        $myClass = new MyClass();   

        for ($c = 0; $c < $num; $c++) {

            $value = $data[$c];      
            $myClass->Date = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You script works fine.
I think, that you just get wrong row. You can check not only date, but id too.

```
if ($row === 1) {
```

Line №1 is really second, and your field names are at №0:

```
if ($row === 0) {
```

There is no conversions, it's just string value.